# Twilio IVR Speech Recognition

Tags: twilio, ivr

I'm new to developing IVR with twilio studio so I started with the basic template and even that's not working.

This is the log:
LOG
Split Based On...
DETAIL
Input evaluated to 'Sales.' from '{{widgets.gather_input.SpeechResult}}'
Transitioning to 'say_play_1' because 'Sales.' did not match any expression

The split is set to "Equal to" sales which then connects the call to a number. It's obviously recognizing the correct speech input but still not working.  Any ideas?

```
{
  "description": "IVR",
  "states": [
    {
      "name": "Trigger",
      "type": "trigger",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "event": "incomingMessage"
        },
        {
          "next": "gather_input",
          "event": "incomingCall"
        },
        {
          "event": "incomingRequest"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": 250,
          "y": 50
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "gather_input",
      "type": "gather-input-on-call",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "split_key_press",
          "event": "keypress"
        },
        {
          "next": "split_speech_result",
          "event": "speech"
        },
        {
          "event": "timeout"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "voice": "alice",
        "speech_timeout": "auto",
        "offset": {
          "x": 290,
          "y": 250
        },
        "loop": 1,
        "hints": "support,sales",
        "finish_on_key": "",
        "say": "Hello, how can we direct your call? Press 1 for sales, or say sales. To reach support, press 2 or say support.",
        "language": "en",
        "stop_gather": false,
        "gather_language": "en-US",
        "profanity_filter": "false",
        "timeout": 5
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "split_key_press",
      "type": "split-based-on",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "event": "noMatch"
        },
        {
          "next": "connect_call_to_sales",
          "event": "match",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "friendly_name": "1",
              "arguments": [
                "{{widgets.gather_input.Digits}}"
              ],
              "type": "equal_to",
              "value": "1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "next": "connect_call_to_support",
          "event": "match",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "friendly_name": "2",
              "arguments": [
                "{{widgets.gather_input.Digits}}"
              ],
              "type": "equal_to",
              "value": "2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "input": "{{widgets.gather_input.Digits}}",
        "offset": {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 510
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "split_speech_result",
      "type": "split-based-on",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "say_play_1",
          "event": "noMatch"
        },
        {
          "next": "connect_call_to_sales",
          "event": "match",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "friendly_name": "sales",
              "arguments": [
                "{{widgets.gather_input.SpeechResult}}"
              ],
              "type": "equal_to",
              "value": "sales"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "next": "connect_call_to_support",
          "event": "match",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "friendly_name": "support",
              "arguments": [
                "{{widgets.gather_input.SpeechResult}}"
              ],
              "type": "equal_to",
              "value": "support"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "input": "{{widgets.gather_input.SpeechResult}}",
        "offset": {
          "x": 510,
          "y": 510
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "connect_call_to_sales",
      "type": "connect-call-to",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "event": "callCompleted"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 750
        },
        "caller_id": "{{contact.channel.address}}",
        "noun": "number",
        "to": "12222222",
        "timeout": 30
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "connect_call_to_support",
      "type": "connect-call-to",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "event": "callCompleted"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": 520,
          "y": 750
        },
        "caller_id": "{{contact.channel.address}}",
        "noun": "number",
        "to": "12222222",
        "timeout": 30
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "say_play_1",
      "type": "say-play",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "gather_input",
          "event": "audioComplete"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": 710,
          "y": 200
        },
        "loop": 1,
        "say": "not valid choice."
      }
    }
  ],
  "initial_state": "Trigger",
  "flags": {
    "allow_concurrent_calls": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That is weird behaviour, mainly because the log says "evaluated to **'Sales.'**". Split widgets conditions are not case-sensitive and should trim leading and following white-space. For some reason this appears to have a capital "S" and a full-stop.

I would suggest a couple of things. Firstly, raise a ticket with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to look into why the condition didn't match correctly.

Then, try some of the other conditions. When I generate a new IVR template in Studio, the conditions use "Matches any of" instead of "Equal to". You might also try "Contains".

So, experiment with the ways you can match the operators, but get support involved to drill down into why it didn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The period is needed after the word for some reason...I just put both, for example:

"1, 1., Uno, Uno., Una, Una., Uno, Uno., Español, Español., Español, Español., Español, Español."